# Facebook Login with Blackberry Webworks

Tags: facebook, blackberry

So I'm trying to build a Blackberry Webworks that integrates with Facebook.

I'm trying to use the Javascript API provided by Facebook, but I'm having some issues with logging in.

The typical "FB.login" function creates a popup, and this doesn't show up on a Blackberry so using that is no good.

Another issue is that I have no idea what to set as the redirect_url for the oauth login, because Webworks pages are referenced locally (local://index.html), and the API rejects this as a valid url. (I've also tried just index.html, but this also causes an error)

And finally, I have no idea what to use for the Mobile Website URL on the Application settings and not sure what other settings to use. Since users will be coming from a Webworks app, Facebook is rejecting login requests if I try to call the oauth url directly. (191 Error).

Comment: blackberry.invoke might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210856/blackberry-webworks-facebook-share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the only viable way to do this is to have a web server that will go through the OAuth2 authentication process documented by Facebook.

What you can do in Blackberry is open a new window or to use a Blackberry BrowserField that links to the web server, that way, your page will be able to get the oauth token that you can use to make Graph API calls.